# NaN error displayed when I use pm.request.body.raw in Postman

Tags: postman

I pass the below params in the request body:

```
{   
    "locale": "en",
    "type": "abc",
    "model": {
        "id": "123"
    }
}
```

in raw JSON format.

I am trying to retrieve the same params in the test tab using `requestBody= JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw);` but then I get a `NaN` when I write the output to the console.

How could I retrieve the params sent in body request to my test scripts?

Comment: How do you want to use the data in the Tests tab? Just log it to the console?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in the `Tests` tab to log any value from that request body:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw).locale)
console.log(JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw).type)
console.log(JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw).model)
console.log(JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw).model.id)
```